# In Scala 3 (dotty) or Scala 2, how to make dependent types transitive?

Tags: scala, dependent-type, type-systems, scala-3, dotty

Here is a simple example:

```scala
  { // dependent type in function
    def dep[B](a: Any, bs: Seq[B]): Seq[(a.type, B)] = {

      val result: Seq[(a.type, B)] = bs.map { b =>
        (a: a.type) -> (b: B)
      }
      result
    }

    val ss = dep(3, Seq("a"))

    val ss2: Seq[(3, String)] = ss
  }
```

It works because `a.type` automatically resolves to `3.type` at call site, despite that `a` doesn't even have a deterministic path at definition site.

Works fine so far, but with a little twist, the call site expansion will no longer work:

```scala
  { // in case class
    class Dep[B](a: Any, bs: Seq[B]) {
      def result: Seq[(a.type, Any)] = {

        val result: Seq[(a.type, B)] = bs.map { b =>
          (a: a.type) -> (b: B)
        }
        result
      }
    }

    object ss extends Dep(3, Seq("a"))

    val ss2: Seq[(3, String)] = ss.result
  }

/*
Found:    Seq[((ss.a : Any), Any)]
Required: Seq[((3 : Int), String)]

Explanation
===========

Tree: ss.result
I tried to show that
  Seq[((ss.a : Any), Any)]
conforms to
  Seq[((3 : Int), String)]
but the comparison trace ended with `false`:
*/
```

Since `Dep` is now a class constructor, the call site will stick to its member type definition instead of call site type. This caused a lot of confusion and violation of constructor function principles, Is there a way to augment the compiler to unify these 2 cases?

The closest I could come up with is to use an auxiliary constructor, but it only generates some inscrutable compiling error:

```scala
  { // in case class, as auxiliary constructor
    case class Dep[A, B](a: A, bs: Seq[B]) {

      def this[B](a: Any, bs: Seq[B]) = this[a.type, B](a, bs)

      def result: Seq[(A, Any)] = {

        val result: Seq[(A, B)] = bs.map { b =>
          (a: A) -> (b: B)
        }
        result
      }
    }
  }

/*
None of the overloaded alternatives of constructor Dep in class Dep with types
 [A, B](): Dep[A, B]
 [A, B](a: A, bs: Seq[B]): Dep[A, B]
match arguments (Null)
*/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a suggestion that avoids all the trouble with constructors our auxiliary types `A` for `a`:

```
  abstract class Dep[B](bs: Seq[B]) {
    val a: Any
    def result: Seq[(a.type, B)] = bs.map(a -> _)
  }
  
  object Obj extends Dep(Seq("a")):
    val a: 3 = 3
  
  val s: Seq[(3, String)] = Obj.result
```

The point is that it doesn't let any values disappear into / resurface from any calls (method calls or constructor calls): it just *defines* a completely static `a` on a completely static singleton object.

I've found that the same pattern scales just fine to much more complex `Obj`-definitions with lots of subcomponents, which in turn have many more dependent member types that are much more complicated that the singleton `.type`. Additionally, it provides a good place for the compiler to `inline` all the macros defined in `Dep1` ... `DepN` into the `Obj` (something that doesn't work with constructors at all, because you cannot pass macros into constructors).

Comment: wow, why didn't I think of that :) Accepted & awarded

Comment: I wonder if a future Scala version could automatically rewrite into your refined version, the current design of making constructor function behaving like Java constructor feels so 90s and out of place

Comment: ... and it composes poorly with other Scala features, like the capability to declare `a` an implicit argument

Answer (score 0):

I don't think auxiliary constructors can have their own type parameters (or construct an instance of a different type). Another problem is that even if you could define that constructor, that would make it ambiguous (`new Dep(1, Seq("foo"))` matches both).

For the same (latter) reason `apply` doesn't work too. The best I could think of, is just make another "factory method":

```
case class Dep[A, B](a: A, bs: Seq[B]) {
 def result = bs.map { a -> _ }
}

object Dep { 
  def narrow[B](a: Any, bs: Seq[B]): Dep[a.type, B] = new Dep(a, bs)
}

Dep.narrow(3, Seq("foo", "bar")).result
```

If you are willing to swap the parameters around `case class Dep[A, B](bs: Seq[B], a: A)` or add an extra dummy param to resolve the ambiguity, then you could just use `apply`:

```
case class Dep[A, B](a: A, bs: Seq[B], dummy: Int) {
 def result = bs.map { a -> _ }
}

object Dep { 
  def apply[B](a: Any, bs: Seq[B]): Dep[a.type, B] = new Dep(a, bs, 0)
}

Dep(3, Seq("foo", "bar")).result
```

**But** if you are just looking to construct a specialized object, then this works:

```
object ss extends Dep[3, String](3, Seq("foo"))
val ss2: Seq[(3, String)] = ss.result
```

Comment: that's not a good solution, factory method cannot be called by subclasses, unlike constructors

Comment: Extending case classes isn't really a good idea in the first place. But you don't need factory method for that. Take a look at the last paragraph to see how to invoke the constructor via sub-class.

Comment: I see ... unfortunately the explicit type argument `3` could be a very long & intractable signature, and writing it down every time will defeat the purpose of dependent type. Is there a way to use dependent type in constructor?

Comment: In addition, this also implies that constructors are not functions, which appears to be a problematic language design

Comment: You don't need to "write it down every time", only when you define the object. Besides, one way or another, you would have to write it down either way somewhere: how else would you specify the type? Constructors are indeed _not functions_. In fact, they are not even _methods_ (at least, not in scala or java). 
And I am not sure this is the right forum for complaints about language design :)